# Getting a syntax error when subpartitioning in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, partitioning

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to subpartition a table in MySQL. There's no error when trying to use either of the methods for a regular partition, just with subpartitioning. It's the last 2 lines that cause the error and I'm a bit lost.

I've also tried switching around KEY to HASH, and LIST to RANGE for the main partition, but still throws the error.

```
  CREATE TABLE `map_polygon` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `district_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `map_type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_big_data` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `polygon_group` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `sort_order` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `locations` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    `north` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `south` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `east` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `west` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `group_north` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `group_south` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `group_east` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `group_west` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_by_user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_by_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`district_id`, `is_big_data`),
    KEY `map_polygons_created_by_user_id_foreign` (`created_by_user_id`),
    KEY `map_polygons_deleted_by_user_id_foreign` (`deleted_by_user_id`),
    KEY `map_polygons_map_type_id_foreign` (`map_type_id`),
    KEY `map_polygons_district_id_foreign` (`district_id`),
    KEY `is_big_data` (`is_big_data`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
  PARTITION BY LIST(is_big_data)
  PARTITIONS 2 (
    PARTITION pNormal VALUES IN (0),
    PARTITION pBigData VALUES IN (1)
  )
  SUBPARTITION BY KEY(district_id)
  SUBPARTITIONS 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a slight rearrangement of the partition clause it seems (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d746)

```
  PARTITION BY LIST(is_big_data)
  SUBPARTITION BY KEY(district_id)
  SUBPARTITIONS 10
  (
    PARTITION pNormal VALUES IN (0),
    PARTITION pBigData VALUES IN (1)
  );
```